# Tuple Index Out of Range (PyQt + Mysqldb)

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt4, mysql-python

i'm put a form from PyQt4,i take the example, from a previous answer, but i'm getting the "Tuple index out of range".
My code is follow.

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT id_cliente as 'Codigo del cliente', nombre AS 'Nombre' FROM t_clientes")
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        if row  == None:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "No hay Datos .... " , QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
            return
        ver_tabla.setRowCount(len(row))
        ver_tabla.setColumnCount(3)
        ##rellenamos la tabla con los datos ...
        for i in range (len(row)):
            for j in range (3):
                item = QTableWidgetItem('%s' % (row[i][j + 1]))
                ver_tabla.setItem(i, j, item)
        layout_btn_clientes.addWidget(ver_tabla,3,0,5,3)
```

> File "/home/admino/Proyectos/TM/recursosh.py", line 102, in **init**
>       item = QTableWidgetItem('%s' % (row[i][j + 1])) IndexError: tuple index out of range

thanks for the help, i'm taking notes about this problems, im thinking, its easy to resolve but i dont find the proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see your `SQL` code, result of this should be 2 column x N row (N is number of record);

```
SELECT id_cliente as 'Codigo del cliente', nombre AS 'Nombre' FROM t_clientes
```

So, `tuple` of record should be look-like this (2 column x N row);

```
record = (
    (u'Data column 1.1', u'Data column 1.2'),
    (u'Data column 2.1', u'Data column 2.2'),
    ...
    (u'Data column M.N', u'Data column M.N'),
)
```

Then show all data in record, easy to use by loop `for`;

```
for row in range (len(record)):
    for column in range(len(record[row])): # For proof concept. I know is overhead, your can replace with 2.
        print record[row][column]
```

So your question, problem is `Index Out of Range` as says in python error. To fix it please use right index reference by calculate before use it (not code it directly);

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id_cliente as 'Codigo del cliente', nombre AS 'Nombre' FROM t_clientes")
listsRecord = cursor.fetchall()
if listsRecord:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "No hay Datos .... " , QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
    return

lengthRow    = len(listsRecord)
lengthColumn = len(listsRecord[0]) # column is 2 at all
yourQTableWidget.setRowCount(lengthRow)
yourQTableWidget.setColumnCount(lengthColumn)
for row in range (lengthRow):
    for column in range (lengthColumn):
        itemQTableWidgetItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(listsRecord[row][column]))
        yourQTableWidget.setItem(row, column, itemQTableWidgetItem)
```

---

Example for test it;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

myQApplication   = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
yourQTableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
listsRecord = (('BRA001', 'ARCELIA EUGENIA'), ('DTA001', 'ALEJANDRA'), ('EDM001', 'ESPACIOS DE DISENO Y MUEBLES'), ('EIE001', 'EDMUNDO')) # Simulate data
lengthRow    = len(listsRecord)
lengthColumn = len(listsRecord[0])
yourQTableWidget.setRowCount(len(listsRecord))
yourQTableWidget.setColumnCount(lengthColumn)
for i in range (lengthRow):
    for j in range (lengthColumn):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(listsRecord[i][j]))
        yourQTableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)
yourQTableWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

**Experimental result** : Windows 7, Python 2.7 x86, PyQt4

[image]

Comment: Huumm???? please show result of `cursor.fetchall()` (By print to cinsole) before add in table. Thanks.

Comment: (('BRA001', 'ARCELIA EUGENIA'), ('DTA001', 'ALEJANDRA'), ('EDM001', 'ESPACIOS DE DISENO Y MUEBLES'), ('EIE001', 'EDMUNDO') ...

Comment: It's work fine for me. Huuuhh? check your code and try `QTableWidget` example in my answer.

Comment: sry that was my fault .. i dont have the correct indent

Comment: how to change the title (1 and 2 in the tableView) ? (sry if other question) if this .. is not correct,please, btw, i edit my question and put it...

Comment: Hey friend, as in PyQt document, it have `QTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels (self, QStringList labels)`for available to create header. Your can try learning it.